# Ember multiple Json request Error while loading route Object has no method 'addArrayObserver'

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, ember.js

im having a problem with my ember app. Im new to it, and trying to do something fun. So the idea of this app is to go and fetch a list of artists from a server via an ajax call, and then if you click the artist it will go to the server again and fetch the albums via another ajax call.

So the first part is working, it is actually fetching the artists through the ajax call when i click on "music library", but then when clicking on the artist it throws the following error:

> Assertion failed: Error while loading route: TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'addArrayObserver'

I've read so many different options, and i think im on the right track because by printing on the console i can see that it is actually going to the server and fetching the right artist's albums, but the error is throw at the last moment, so it is not displaying the albums. I was also able to show the albums when reloading or typing the url (not now, since i changed the code to implement the afterModel)

So, here is my code:

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
LOG_TRANSITIONS: true,
LOG_TRANSITIONS_INTERNAL: true
});

App.Library = Ember.Object.extend({
name: null,
artist: []
});

App.Library.reopenClass({
loadArtist: function() {
        var artistList = Em.A();
        $.getJSON('url').then(function(data){

            //json parsing, creating a library object and putting it into the array         

        });
        return artistList;
}   
});

App.Artist = Ember.Object.extend({
id: null,
name: null,
coverArt: null,
albumCount: null
});

App.Albums = Ember.Object.extend({
albums: []
});

App.Artist.reopenClass({
loadAlbums: function(params) {
    var albumsJson = 'url' + params.artist_id +'';
    var albumList = Em.A();
    $.getJSON(albumsJson).then(function(data){

    //parsing json, creating artist objects and pushing them into the array

            }); 
    return albumList;
    //});
}

});


/*****************************ROUTER**************************************************************************************/

App.Router.map(function() {
  // put your routes here
this.resource('library', function() {
    this.resource('artist', { path: '/:artist_id'});  
    });


});


App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
model: function() {
    var hi = ['Welcome'];
    return hi;
}
});

App.LibraryRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
model: function() {

    return App.Library.loadArtist();
}
});

App.ArtistRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
model: function(params) {

    this.transitionTo('artist', params);

},

afterModel: function(params, transition){

    var artist = Em.A();
    if(params.artist_id==null){
        artist.push(App.Artist.create({artist_id: params.id}));
    } else {
        artist.push(App.Artist.create({artist_id: params.artist_id}));
    }

    return App.Artist.loadAlbums(artist[0]);
}
});


/**************************************CONTROLLERS***********************************************************************************/

App.ArtistController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
needs: "library"
});

App.LibraryController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({});
```

I would really appreciate some help!

Also, the HTML is as follows:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <div class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My Library</a>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>{{#linkTo 'index'}}Home{{/linkTo}}</li>
                <li>{{#linkTo 'library'}}Music Library{{/linkTo}}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    {{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    <div class="container">
            {{#each item in model}}
            <h1>{{item}}</h1>
            {{/each}}
    </div>
</script>
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="library">
<div class="container"> 
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <table class="table">
                {{#each model}}
                    <tr><td>
                        {{name}}
                    </td></tr>
                        {{#each artist}}
                        <tr><td>
                            {{#linkTo 'artist' this}}
                                {{name}}
                            {{/linkTo}}
                            <!--<a {{action 'selectArtist' this}}> {{name}} </a>-->
                        </td></tr>
                        {{/each}}
                {{/each}}       
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <p>Albumes</p>
            {{outlet}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="artist">
<div class="container"> 
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <table class="table">
            <tr><td><p>{{controllers.library.artist.name}}</p></td></tr>
            {{#each itemController='album'}}
                <tr><td>
                    {{{name}}}
                </td></tr>
            {{/each}}       
        </table>
    </div>  
</div>
</script>
```

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Hi, I think you should carefully look at this section in your template: `{{#each itemController='album'}}
                <tr><td>
                    {{{name}}}
                </td></tr>
            {{/each}}` Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, i solved it using this question:

[Why isn't my ember.js route model being called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15678817/why-isnt-my-ember-js-route-model-being-called/15679087#15679087)

Instead of putting the logic in the model or afterModel, i just needed to set the controller.

Hope it helps to someone.

Best!

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the error you need to modify the `model` function of the `App.ArtistRoute`, to return an array as `App.ArtistController` is an `Ember.ArrayController`.
For example,

```
App.ArtistRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
model: function(params) {

    //this.transitionTo('artist', params);
  return [];

},
....
```

Or even place the code of `afterModel` function in `model` function to retrieve the albums of this artist.

Although i'm not certain if you really want the model of your artist context to be the albums, it does not look correct to me. I would suggest to make the `App.ArtistController` aν `Ember.ObjectController`, assign the model to an `App.Artist` object and store the albums related to this artist in a property of the `App.Artist` class. In that case you will need to add a property in `App.Artist` and create a class of `App.Album`.

With this in mind have a look at the following example which is a very rough modification of your code *(caution the App.ArtistController has not been switched instead its model is an array of albums)*,
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/AdOfiyiN/2#/library/2

Comment: Thanks for your response, ill will give a try to what you are saying. As far as the model / afterModel, i had the code in the model before, but since the model hook is not called when the "linkTo" or "TransisionTo" is called, I moved the logic to the afterModel. I will try making an objectController instead of an ArrayController. I'll let you know. Thanks!

Comment: To me it also makes more sense to put all this logic in the Model, but then the "LinkTo" is usless... bah