# a bit confused about Ember's behavior and whether the model hook is called in a detail route

Tags: ember.js

I am learning a bit of Ember and trying to implement with some of our data. I have the following which is esentially a master - detail and need the detail to make a JSON call that would be implemented in the model hook:

```
 <script type='text/x-handlebars' data-template-name='inventoryperiods'>
   before loop
    {{#each}}
       <div>{{#link-to "ipshow" this}}{{id}}{{/link-to}}</div>
    {{/each}}
</script>
...
Inv.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('inventoryperiods', {path: '/'});
  this.route('ipshow', {path: '/ip/:ip_id'});
});

Inv.InventoryperiodsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {

    return [{id:1, name:"Frank"}, {id:2, name:"Allan"}];  
  }
});

Inv.IpshowRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        alert('within period detail model' + params.ip_id);
        var my_name="Jonathan " + params.ip_id;
        return {name:my_name};
    }
});
```

and when I go to '/' - I get the list but clicking on 1 gives me Frank when I think that the model hook should be called and give me 'Jonathan 1'. I get the idea that I'm passing this but it seems like there should be a way to tell the route that there is more detail that I need than exists in that object.

In jsbin: http://jsbin.com/qazoz/3/edit?html,output

and to see that Jonathan 1 comes out if I go to that directly, go to: http://jsbin.com/qazoz/3#/ip/1

I see this discussion: [Why isn't my ember.js route model being called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15678817/why-isnt-my-ember-js-route-model-being-called)

> Ember has the assumption, that you do not necessarily make a call to
>   the model hook, if you use {{linkTo}}. In your places template you use
>   {{#linkTo 'place' place}} {{place.name}} {{/linkTo}}. You are passing
>   a place object to your route. Ember assumes that this is the same
>   object, that you would get when executing your model hook. So from
>   Embers View there is no need to call the model hook. So if you want to
>   perform retrieval logic even when you use linkTo, use the
>   setupController hook.

but the adding the setupController doesn't seem to change this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

so it seems the answer is to pass the id rather than an object in the link-so `{{#link-to "ipshow" id}}{{id}}{{/link-to}}`